# Partial Implementation of TypeScript Interface with overloaded methods

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following TypeScript definitions:

```
interface ServiceMethods<T> {
  create (data: T): T;

  create (data: T[]): T[];
}

declare let Service: ServiceMethods<number>

// x is of type number[]
const x = Service.create([2, 3]);

// y is of type number
const y = Service.create(1);
```

However partial implementation is also allowed.

```
class Test implements Partial<ServiceMethods<number>> {
  create(data: number) {
    return data;
  }
}
```

The above resulted in the following errors:

```
Property 'create' in type 'Test' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Partial<ServiceMethods<number>>'.
  Type '(data: number) => number' is not assignable to type '{ (data: number): number; (data: number[]): number[]; }'.
    Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
      Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2416)
```

Any resolution?

Comment: This is expected behavior. Two possible fixes: 1) Rename one of the `create` method signatures in `ServiceMethods`, like to `createArray` or 2) write `create(data: number | number[]): any { ... }` in `Test`. `Partial` is not needed for this to work.

Comment: The goal is to infer the return type from the arguments type. See the create method here for more details: https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#create-data-params